# Add keypress event to classes without JQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, eventhandler

The code below attaches event handlers for clicks, but is not working for keyboard events. I don't want just the `document.keypress` but specific class elements for keyboard events. So I have 'test' written out which works for mouse clicks fine, but not for any of the keyboard events.

```
  function test(className, fnCall, eventToApply){
    if(typeof document.getElementById('x').getElementsByClassName(className) !='undefined') {
                    var els = document.getElementById('x').getElementsByClassName(className);
                    for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                        if(els[i].addEventListener) { //Undefined for keypress events
                          els[i].addEventListener(eventName,  function(e) { fnCall(e); }); }
                        else {  //Hardcode for testing
                           els[i].onclick = function(e) { fnCall(e); };     
                            els[i].onkeypress = function(e) { fnCall(e); } //doesn't work!
                        }
                    }
```

The document onkeypress works though, but I am unable to set up individual element handlers on document ready or the keypress itself.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
                   //This works, but setting up events for each class type element doesn't work for keypress 
        })
```

In other words, is there an equivalent to do the below, without using JQuery:

```
 document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
       //This works in Jquery
        $('.customClass-'+ event.keycode).click(); 
  });



document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
 //This doesn't register, says undefined for any event or attachEvenHandler/attachEvent    
 test('.class'+event.keycode, myFunction() , 'keypress');

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("customClass-" + event.keycode);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].click();
    }
});
```

w3school documenations

- [HTML DOM click() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)
- [HTML DOM getElementsByClassName()Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)
- [HTML DOM addEventListener() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, you may want to provide some context into why it fixes the problem.